# How can i turn on MobileNetwork?

Tags: android

I tried to turn on MobileNetwork by using code below,but it does not work and it throws **NoSuchMethodexception **. How can I turn on MOBILE NETWORK without NoSuchMethodException?

```
public void setMobileDataEnabled(boolean enabled,Context ctx) {
    try{
        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(cm);      
        final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled",Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

And this is permission I Added.

"android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing the WIFI state :

```
WifiManager wifiManager ;
wifiManager  = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);        //True - to enable WIFI connectivity .
```

For accessing the DATA/3G state :

```
ConnectivityManager dataManager;
dataManager  = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, true);        //True - to enable data connectivity .
```

Now you need to add this permissions in Manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```